# MEAN codes to obtain a full stack website for tables

Tags: angular, mean, streamlit

I have data in Mongodb consisting of information and entities obtained via web scrapping and apis. I want to obtain a code that displays 4 things -

1. display selected data on the basis of first name initials
2. display selected data on the basis of first name and last name initials
3. full mongo db table for lok sabha collection except id entity
4. full mongo db table for rajya sabha collection except id entity

I have obtained all the required data listed above through streamlit, but streamlit is not an effective way to make it public. I mean the same data of 4 things obtained through streamlit to be obtained through MEAN stack with proper CSS. Please help me in this conversion from streamlit to MEAN stack. I am facing problem how to proceed.